# How do I convert my pymysql query result to json format?

Tags: python, flask, pymysql

I'm making an API for which I'd need to return json.

Below is my views.py

```
from flask.json import jsonify
from team2_project import app
from team2_project import cursor
import json
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/')
def index():
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM Clients_002")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    formulas = cursor.fetchall()

    return str(formulas)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb
import pymysql.cursors
app = Flask(__name__)
connection = pymysql.connect(host='',
                             user='',
                             password='',
                             db='',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

import team2_project.views
```

my function returns:

```
[{"clientCompID_002": 1, "clientCompName_002": "Telus", "clientCity_002": "Halifax", "clientCompPassword_002": "002", "moneyOwed_002": "100"}, {"clientCompID_002": 2, "clientCompName_002": "Bell", "clientCity_002": "Dartmouth", "clientCompPassword_002": "002", "moneyOwed_002": "10"}, {"clientCompID_002": 3, "clientCompName_002": "Purple Cow", "clientCity_002": "Bedford", "clientCompPassword_002": "002", "moneyOwed_002": "120"}, {"clientCompID_002": 4, "clientCompName_002": "Apple", "clientCity_002": "Toronto", "clientCompPassword_002": "002", "moneyOwed_002": "1210"}, {"clientCompID_002": 5, "clientCompName_002": "Sowo", "clientCity_002": "Montreal", "clientCompPassword_002": "002", "moneyOwed_002": "1110"}]
```

How do output it in json with indentations? I tried jsonify() however it returns the same result as str(). Cant seem to get rid of the square brackets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the json package's `dumps()` method, it has an indentation parameter you can use.

example:
`json.dumps(formulas, indent=4)`

Comment: it still returns the same output with square brackets.

Comment: The square brackets are supposed to be there, I am not sure what you're asking. You have a list of objects, and to denote that JSON uses square brackets.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that json needs to begin with curly braces only

Comment: If you're only dealing with one object sure, but in your case, because you're pulling rows out of a database, you have multiple JSON objects which are denoted as if they were a list, so in this case it makes sense, it's still valid JSON.

Comment: If you really want to you can create a new object and stick it inside a dict key but it's sort of unnecessary. `new_formulas= {"dataset": formulas}`

Comment: cool thanks! the indent doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `fetchall()`, array of dict will be returned. To get a single object you just `fetchone()`. So, try,

```
formulas = cursor.fetchone()
```